# Android : Bluetooth device return unknown character like "?"

Tags: android, bluetooth

We develop android app to connect with Bluetooth weight scale device,This device sending a data and our app parse this data and display in app.

So my problem is to read data from Bluetooth device.

Device is successfully paired and connect with android app, and device sending a data properly but when i received this data is, unknown character like "��".

So how can i read or parse data ?  Please check below code to read data from Bluetooth device .

```
 public DeviceConnectThread(BluetoothSocket socket, Handler mHandler) {
    this.mHandler = mHandler;
    mSocket = socket;
    InputStream tmpIn = null;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;

    // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
    // member streams are final
    try {
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "<---------------- I / O stream exceptopn ----------->");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mInStream = tmpIn;
    mOutStream = tmpOut;
}

public void run() {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes = 0; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mInStream.read(buffer);


            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message read exception \n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Handler message >> " + msg);
        byte[] buf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

        switch (msg.what) {

            case Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(buf);
                Log.i(TAG, "Write Message : " + writeMessage);
                showMessage("Message Sent : " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(buf, 0, msg.arg1);

                showMessage("Message Received : " + readMessage);
                tvReadableData.setText("Readable Data : \n" + readMessage);
                tvReadableData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MainActivity.tvExp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
```

Whats wrong here ????

Comment: There are not always human readable characters inside a stream with a Bluetooth device. You have to actually check the bits with the manual of the device.

Comment: @MuratK.  As per manual may be bit range is BIT11-BIT0, however I don't know where I need to set in my code can you please guide me to set this?  here is screenshort of my manual http://prntscr.com/fb6h1c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution.

Bluetooth device return data in "bytes", So we need to convert this bytes in "BITS"(As per our device manual).

Now read this "BITS" manual wise and separate data.

```
 bytes = mInStream.read(buffer);
            Log.d(TAG, "byte >> " + Arrays.toString(buffer));
            String bit = HexUtil.byteToBit(buffer);
            Log.d(TAG, "Bit " + bit);
            int data = Integer.parseInt(bit.substring(0, 1), 2);
            Log.d(TAG, "Data = " + data);



public static String byteToBit(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < Byte.SIZE * bytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append((bytes[i / Byte.SIZE] << i % Byte.SIZE & 0x80) == 0 ? '0'
                : '1');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```